# Browsermob IOException with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I´m pretty new using Browsermob. I have a Project which uses Selenium WebDriver. Because of some pages having script issues I´d like to use a Browsermob ProxyDriver for my WebDriver but i always get an Exception which causes Selenium to fail in getting the pages HTML.

This is my declaration of the WebDriver and the Browsermob ProxyDriver:

```
ProxyServer proxy = new ProxyServer(9090);
proxy.start();

final Proxy proxy = proxy.seleniumProxy();

final DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

final FirefoxProfile profile = getFirefoxProfile();

this.proxy.setRequestTimeout(10000);
this.driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(), profile, capabilities);
```

And this is the only noticeable console output:

```
WARN 01/27 16:49:09 o.b.p.BrowserMobPro~ - IOException while trying to report an HTTP
INFO 01/27 16:49:09 o.b.p.h.BrowserMobH~ - EOFException(java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error) when requesting [...]
WARN 01/27 16:49:10 o.b.p.BrowserMobPro~ - IOException while trying to report an HTTP error
INFO 01/27 16:49:10 o.b.p.h.BrowserMobH~ - EOFException(java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error) when requesting [...]
```

Has anyone an idea about this issue?

**Edit:** The error is thrown no matter which webpage I try to open.

Comment: Does the page you load contains any flash? Seems like those errors could be coming from .swf files on the page.

Comment: No, there´s no flash. Interestingly, the error is thrown on every site.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve the issue by now? If yes, it'd be nice if you could share the solution. I am getting the same warnings. There seems to be no impact on my test cases though.

Comment: I was not able to resolve this by now so I´ve decided to work without BrowserMob.